# How to apply max length to a view till second view reach parent end

Tags: android

I have a text view and rating bar align horizontally.Rating bar start after the end of rating bar.

[image]

When this text of the text view get too long to fit in the screen it will push rating bar off the screen. In a case like this I want text view to take space in the screen until the point where rating bar touch screen end and show 3 dots in the end of the text view. But if text is short rating bar should start after that.

Please explain a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have to explore constraint layout, for now solution of you isssue is here. I hope this may help you.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="sandeep sankla"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/rating_layout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. In your example, if the text is too short there will be a space between text and rating bar. Textview won't get short when text is short. I'm using ConstraintLayout.